# Display the taxonomy name of the current term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, register-taxonomy

I have a hierarchical taxonomy with lots of terms in hierarchical order.

No matter what term i'm viewing I'd like to be able to display the custom taxonomy name (as per what i've registered it as `singular_name`) on that page. I've searched here and the WP forums to death but had no luck.

I found this but it only displays the slug, not the name...

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );    
echo $term->taxonomy;
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name )` will give you an object containing all of the taxonomy metadata:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$this_tax = get_taxonomy( $queried_object->taxonomy );
echo $this_tax->labels->singular_name;
```

Comment: @JacobPeattie true, it's a *partial* taxonomy object, but not nearly complete, depending on what you're after.