# IF taxonomy archive is hierarchical THEN

Tags: taxonomy, conditional-tags, archive-template

I'm trying to put in a conditional in my `archive.php` that sorts our whether the taxonomy is hierarchical or not. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work.

```
<?php if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical() ) { ?>
I am a hierarchical tax 
<?php } else { ?>
I am NOT a hierarchical tax 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_taxonomy_hierarchical/) (*please* read the docs) for `is_taxonomy_hierarchical()`. You need to tell it which taxonomy you're checking:

```
if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( 'my_taxonomy_name' ) ) {

}
```

If you're template isn't specific to a taxonomy, and you need to know which taxonomy you're viewing, use `get_queried_object()` to figure it out (you were [already told](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/326730/display-the-taxonomy-name-of-the-current-term) how to do this, by the way):

```
if ( is_tax() ) {
    $taxonomy = get_queried_object()->taxonomy;

    if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) ) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: I read the docs. I didn't remember the other question.